# Missing comment on profile?

Tags: discussion, support, comments

I have received some comments in this topic, [Need the last entry while using XSUM in SYNCSORT JCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400186/need-the-last-entry-while-using-xsum-in-syncsort-jcl/18459986#comment27160653_18459986)

To see if the TS/OP has deigned to turn up and respond to requests, I went to the topic and found a comment @ed to me, but for which I received no notification and which does not appear in my list of comments on my profile.

I've checked about 97 times that @BillWoodger is spelled the same as the other @s.

Is it going to just come along in its own sweet time?

I would have appreciated a timely notification on this one, to close the comment-exchange on good terms.

[image: From the discussion]

[image: From my profile]

Re-tagged as "possible-bug" as I've no clue if I can reproduce it and there does not seem to be a simple answer.

For anyone looking, all the comments have been removed from the post (by the original Commenter) so it might be more tricky to look at. Sorry. I'm sure there are backups with the data in...

Comment: Do you mean [your list of comments (which you made)](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1927206/bill-woodger?tab=activity&sort=comments) or [your list of responses (which were made to you)](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1927206/bill-woodger?tab=responses)?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I would go with the second one...

Comment: @FDinoff just trying to clarify, because that's not what he said.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand, Well, it is the Responses tab, and then Comments. I was unaware that I could list my own comments. The above three arrived on Meta. A further one from Jack on SO. But still the one in question missing.