# I don't always get notification when someone answers my question or comments on my post

Tags: bug, private-beta

I'm participating in private beta of Pets and I've noticed that I don't always get notifications when someone answers my question or comments on my post.

Now someone answered my question and I didn't get the notification. By notification, I mean

[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: Just to check; do you have your notifications open in annother tab? Or annother computer? Do your notification still appear, but as if you've already read them

Comment: I'm on the Pets beta too and seem to have got all of them when on another site. I'm not sure but I think there's a delay so maybe you're checking back before you've received them?

Comment: Don't think it's related to private beta, more likely no-repro case same as [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200362/152859).

Comment: @RichardTingle I have not

Comment: Has happened to me several times on StackOverflow. Found another one recently from June. I only use one computer at a time to look at StackOverflow, and very rarely in more than one tab. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195049/missing-comment-on-profile